# Get page title in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, template, magento-2.0, phtml

I want to **get the page title in a PHTML template file**. Is there a global function I can call to retrieve this?

Comment: From where you need this functionality?

Comment: can you give an example?

Answer (score 13):

At magento every phtml file  have block class.So you get  page title by

```
 $block->getLayout()->getBlock('page.main.title')->getPageTitle()
```

Comment: Good one, however this will fail if the theme has removed this block.

Comment: ya.` Raphael`,you are right.... but this as per as ,.`magento  default theme`

Comment: which phtml file use @Amit Bera

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, there's no global function you can call to retrieve this.

Here are the solutions:

### Quick but not recommended

You can call the following directly in your template file:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$title = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\View\Page\Title');
```

### Quick but unstable

See Amit answer, however, it will fail if the theme ever removes that block.

### Recommended via DI

For this one, you have to have your own custom block that is used to render the template.

First, you need to inject `\Magento\Framework\View\Page\Title` in your block constructor:

```
protected $_pageTitle;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Title $pageTitle
) {
    $this->_pageTitle = $pageTitle;
    ...
}
```

Then you can declare a function in your block class:

```
public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->_pageTitle->getShort();
}
```

And finally you can call it in your template:

```
$block->getTitle();
```

Answer (score 1):

For someone who search cms page title. I get it in my .phtml

`<?= $block->getLayout()->getBlock('cms_page')->getPage()->getTitle(); ?>`

Like that you can get any block $block->getLayout()->getBlock('cms_page') and then get their data

Comment: Yes, it is working. Thank you